# How to use a callback in a render() of React component

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I want to use the result of a server method that does a count on a collection to show it in the render method of a react component. I understand that I must do it from the callback function but it doesn't work for me.

Server Method:

```
export const analysis = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: "analysis",
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    codigo: {
      type: String
    },
    rta: {
      type: String
    }
  }).validator(),
  run(one) {
    const rta = Respuesta.find({
      codigo: one.codigo,
      rtatexto: one.rta,
      activo: true
    }).count();
    console.log(rta);
    return Number(rta);
  }
});
```

Call from client:

```
export default class AnalysisFila extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const one = { codigo: this.props.codigo, rta: this.props.opcion };
    const rta = analysis.call(one, (err, res) => {
      return (
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell> {this.props.opcion} </Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell> {res} </Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
      );
    });
  }
}
```

How do I use the value of *res* in my component's render method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Asynchronous Functions

Before I answer the question, it is important to understand the difference between synchronous and asynchronous functions in JavaScript.

Therefore, if you are new to JavaScript or asynchronous behaviours, I recommend you read up on [this excellent answer and explanation about the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323)

### Explanation for the Problem

The problem here is that React's `render()` method is a synchronous method, meaning React expects a synchronous return value with `jsx` (or a `React.Element` for that matter).

For React, your current render function actually returns nothing or `undefined`, as you do not a have a synchronous `return` statement. And so nothing will get rendered.

React has no way of knowing when your callback is called or what it returns, as it is executed completely out of Reacts context.

### Solution to the Problem

The way to go here is to use Reacts [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) which is exactly for these kind of scenarios.

By using state and the method `setState()`, you can asynchrounously trigger the render-method to be called again as soon as the response from your API delivered the data. Also, with `this.state`, you can bring the response-data into the react-context and let it know about it.

A full example could look like this:

```js
export default class AnalysisFila extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaded: false
      opcion: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const one = { codigo: this.props.codigo, rta: this.props.opcion };
    const rta = analysis.call(one, (err, res) => {
      this.setState({
        loaded: true,
        opcion: res
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const content = this.state.loaded ? this.state.opcion : 'Loading...';
    return (
     <Table.Row>
        <Table.Cell> {this.props.opcion} </Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell> {content} </Table.Cell>
      </Table.Row>
    );
  } 
}
```

I also used the `componentDidMount`-Lifecycle-Method of React, as it is the recommended way to trigger API Calls. You can read more about Lifecycles in the [official lifecycle documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class)

The Life-Cycle of this Component will be like the following:

1. Component will get created and constructor will set an initial value for `this.state`
2. `render()` method is called with `this.state.loading === false` - thus the content will default to the string 'loading...'
3. The `componentDidMount()` function gets called and will trigger your API-Call
4. Your callback is called and executes `setState()`, putting the response-data into `this.state`
5. Now that react knows the state was changed, it calls the `render()` method again. But this time, `this.state.loading === true` and there is some value for `this.state.opcion` - thus the content will be the value from your response.

Comment: I want to thank you very much for your clear and excellent answer, it solved my problem.